# Dart how to make MyClass.of(context) method

Tags: flutter, dart

Say I have this class:

```
class AppTheme {
  final BuildContext context;

  AppTheme(this.context);

  TextStyle caption() {
    return Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.copyWith(
      color: Colors.black
    );
  }
}
```

How can I modify it in a way that I can access `caption` using:

```
AppTheme.of(context).caption();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why would you need it that way, when you can already have it easily using

```
AppTheme(context).caption();
```

But if you really need it, you can try this:

```
class AppTheme {
  final BuildContext context;

  AppTheme._(this.context); // make this constructor private

  static AppTheme of(BuildContext context) => AppTheme._(context); // pass context to above constructor

  TextStyle caption() {
    return Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.copyWith(color: Colors.black);
  }
}
```

And you can use it with

```
AppTheme.of(context).caption();
```